# Bootstrap change container width on ipad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

What I am trying to do is;

I have a ".container" class on Twitter Bootstrap, I want my container class like

```
.container{
  width: 900px (if on ipad)
  width: 970px (if computer)
}
```

what should I do. I've tried the cod below, but .container's width: 900px also in computer.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container{width: 900px!important;}
}
```

How should I update that css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically, one wants to change the CSS based on device/screen dimensions because they want the content to look different based on how much screen real-estate available. *Functionality* may change based on device type using JS, but CSS only handles how it *looks*, and how it *looks* should generally only depend on how much *visual space* is available. Out of curiosity, could you explain why you need different styling based on device type?

Comment: On that note, have you considered using `min-device-width` rather than `min-width`? That would be more accurate in determining the device.

Comment: I need .container{width:900px;}

Comment: That doesn't answer either of the questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .container{max-width: 600px;width: 600px;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container{max-width: 900px;}
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container{max-width: 900px;}
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .container{width: 970px;}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .container{width: 1170px;max-width: 1170px;}
}
```

it is solved thank you all